# Using User defined types in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw, user-defined-types

I am migrating my database from ORACLE to DB2, While doing the migrations I have come across a
situation related to User defined types. As I have been working with DB2 recently, I have been through the SQL standards and have been successful in migrating most of the stuffs.

I am kind of stuck with this UDT and tried with few of the suggestion by some DB experts here, but the thing I am trying to achieve isnt working well.

I have created the below UDT and created another UDT as table and been trying to use in a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "XYZ" AS OBJECT (
   aa           VARCHAR2(30),
   bb   NUMBER (18),
   cc     NUMBER (30, 12),
   count      NUMBER (18),
   value_1             NUMBER (18),
   value_2             NUMBER (18),
   value_3             NUMBER (18),
   display_1           VARCHAR2 (256),
   display_2           VARCHAR2 (256),
   display_3           VARCHAR2 (256),
   status              NUMBER (1)
)
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "XYZ_TBL" AS TABLE OF XYZ;
```

As I have read that If we create a UDT in DB2, DB2 automatically creates a function of the above XYZ without parameters I believe. And to use the UDT, we have to create a function calling the constructor. I created a function with a same name XYZ referencing the UDT.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XYZ(
   aa                  VARCHAR2,
   bb                  NUMBER,
   cc                  NUMBER,
   count               NUMBER,
   value_1             NUMBER,
   value_2             NUMBER,
   value_3             NUMBER,
   display_1           VARCHAR2,
   display_2           VARCHAR2,
   display_3           VARCHAR2,
   status              NUMBER
)
return XYZ
IS
rec      xyz := xyz(cast(null as varchar), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as varchar), cast(null as varchar), cast(NULL as varchar),cast(null as decimal));
BEGIN
    RETURN rec;
END;
```

Every thing got compiled perfectly . And I am calling this function in a package as

```
 FUNCTION get_combinations(aa        VARCHAR2, bb     VARCHAR2,
                              cc  VARCHAR,  dd NUMBER,
                              prefix_1          VARCHAR2, prefix_2       VARCHAR2,
                              prefix_3          VARCHAR2, filter_1       NUMBER,
                              filter_2          NUMBER,   filter_3       NUMBER)
             RETURN xyz_tbl PIPELINED
    IS
        rec      xyz := xyz(cast(null as varchar), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as varchar), cast(null as varchar), cast(NULL as varchar),cast(null as decimal));
        cur      sys_refcursor;
        ccyCol   VARCHAR(64);
        txQuery  VARCHAR(4000);

\\and doing further stuffs
```

Now, When I am using the function in one of the stored procedure, It gives me the below error

> SQL0724N The activation of "XYZ" of type "FUNCTION " would exceed the maximum level of indirect SQL cascading.

and when I try to use the UDT XYZ directly into the package without creating any caller for it, the package is not able to locate XYZ and doesn't compile.

In a package I am using the function XYZ to pass the values from different set of tables and building a dynamic select query for further processing.

May be I am doing something wrong against the SQL standards?

Comment: Good question. This has nothing to do with the SQL Standard, but it's only related to how DB2 handles UDTs. In my experience DB2 comes out of the box configured with [very] low settings for temp areas/spaces. It seems the rule is not to expand them unless it's needed; so, you should ask the DBA team about this.

Comment: I think you can get better answers to this admin question at dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor function for a structured type is [created automatically](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=types-constructor-functions-structured) by Db2. It returns a new object of the type with all fields set to NULL. You would then need to create setter methods to set the fields appropriately.

The "constructor" that you have defined calls itself recursively until it exceeds the [maximum recursion level of 64](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0500-sql0749#sql0724n).

Comment: Thanks. But still it is unclear to me that why my function is not able to access the structured type which is created  on the same user. Even If I have created a setter method through a function where I am assigning null to each parameters, Its not working like as it should.  `rec      xyz := xyz(cast(null as varchar), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as varchar), cast(null as varchar), cast(NULL as varchar),cast(null as decimal)); `